# Which indicator should i use in Topic Clustering with K-Means?

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

I am trying to implement k-means algorithm, the input is a bunch of text files, i want to cluster them into different topics.

The first step is convert those text files into vector samples.

My question is, Which indicator below should i use ? Why ?

1. Word appear or not.
2. Word frequency.
3. TF-IDF.

Comment: I'd suggest that you try them all. There's no predeterminable way to know for *sure* which method is best for your dataset. However, each method you listed does *try* to account for certain things, so if you would like to know what they *try* to do then an answer could possibly include that.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is probably to use around top 50 or so TF-IDF terms for each document (doesn't have to be exactly 50, you should experiment with the number). Going with the full word occurrence vectors likely won't give you good results because of the [high dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).

Alternatively, I recommend exploring [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) and use the topic proportions for each document as features to cluster on.